# is_vat_exempt(); on order for different user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price

Okay the title may not be that clear but I have an issue that seems poorly documented. I'm using a telesales/manual order system and need to work out a vat exempt system for users from another country.

I found the following after a very long search:

```
is_vat_exempt();
```

From what I read this saves in the session of the customer. Which is great. People are able to order without VAT themselves. However. In our telesales system you're often logged in as a admin related role. You fill in the details from the customer or select their account. During this process the so called customer is still the account that is logged in; the seller.

The code works something like this:

```
woocommmerce->customer->is_vat_exempt();
```

To set someone as vat exempt you can use the following:

```
set_is_vat_exempt( $is_vat_exempt );
```

Right now I am simply stuck. Would I be able to make the order vat exempt for the user that is filled in the form? Without changing the session to one for the customer?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the customer variable or order id, like `$customer = new WC_Customer( $order_id );`

then just use `$customer->is_vat_exempt();`. That's all.

Comment: This seems to make sense, I'll play with it and update you ASAP. The only thing I worry about is that prices in the module are called based on the admin. But I will know soon enough.

Comment: Ok, go on. Will wait to hear from you.